# I have a mobile column having data in the format 91-98-91254*** I want to display the data in 3 separate columns separeted by " - "

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query removes the " - " but then after that i want to display each set in 3 different columns`enter code here

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),10),1,3) + ' ' +
       SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),10),4,3) + ' ' +
       SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),10),7,4)
FROM candidate_jitendra
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just list each number term as a separate column in your `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),10),1,3) AS first,
       SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),10),4,3) AS second,
       SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),10),7,4) AS third
FROM candidate_jitendra
```

Answer (score 0):

This is dynamically access the string and also not any hardcore position.

```
Declare @t table (id int, name  varchar(50))

insert into @t (id,name) values( 1    ,'99-98-91254')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 2    ,'99-89-8681')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 3    ,'87')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 4    ,'786-32')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 5    ,'79-45-4')

;WITH Split_Names (Name, xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    Name,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Names><name>'  
    + REPLACE(Name,'-', '</name><name>') + '</name></Names>') AS xmlname
      FROM @t
)

 SELECT       
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)') AS first_name,    
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)') AS last_name,
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[3]','varchar(100)') AS third_name --You can add as you want
 FROM Split_Names
```